# headerStyle dosen't affect header in React-Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am currently learning React-Native with Typescript.
I am working on a project and got this bug.

The bug is that the color dosen't effect my header.

I hope you guys can help me out :D

/Viggo

index.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

import AddCity from './components/AddCity/AddCity'
import Cities from './components/Cities/Cities'
import City from './components/Cities/City'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { colors } from './theme'

const CitiesNav = createStackNavigator({
    Cities: { screen: Cities },
    City: { screen: City }
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.primary
        },
        headerTintColor: '#8e44ad'
    }
})

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Cities: { screen: CitiesNav },
    AddCity: { screen: AddCity }
})

const App = createAppContainer(Tabs);

export default App;
```

theme.tsx

```
const colors = {
    primary: '#D81B60',
}

export { 
    colors
}
```

Comment: did you try to use property headerBackground? and try headerTransparent : true .

Comment: Nope, i will try it now. I will get back to you.

Comment: Can you sent a example code of it? like in my example.

Comment: I can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Just try defaultNavigationOptions instead of navigationOptions. Hope it will work

```
 defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.primary
    },
    headerTintColor: '#8e44ad'
}
```